# java 2dimensional array to string array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two dimensional array with values created as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) 
{
 for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
 {
    array[i][j]=e.getValues (r,c);
 }
}
```

which will return :

```
array[0][0] => 16
array[0][1] => 11
array[0][2] => 7
array[0][3] => 6
array[1][0] => 10
array[1][1] => 7
array[1][2] => 6
array[1][3] => 6
```

how can i store these values as a single string in another 2d string array:

```
arrayValues[0][0] = > {"16,11,7,6"};
arrayValues[1][0] = > {"10,7,6,6"};
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) 
{
   for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
   {
     array[i][j]=e.getValues (r,c);


     arrayValues[i][0] += array[i][j];

     if(j < 3) {
       arrayValues[i][0] += ',';
     }

   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to take array and convert it to one string that contains coma delimited values, do the following:

```
String[] arr = new String[] {1, 2, 3, 4}
String str = Arrays.asList(arr).toString(); // contians "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
String result = str.substring(1, str.length - 1); // contains "1, 2, 3, 4"
```

if you want to remove spaces after comas call `replace(", ", "")`

And please note that 2 dimensional array is an array of arrays, so you can easily apply this way to your 2 dimensional  array be calling this code in loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] newValues = new String[array.length];

for(int i=0;i<newValues.length;i++) {
 for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++) {
     newValues[i]= java.util.Arrays.toString(array[i]);
 }
}
```

You can test this by running:

```
for(int i=0;i<newValues.length;i++) {
    System.out.println(newValues[i]);
}
```

Which will print out:

```
[16, 11, 7, 6]
[10, 7, 6, 6]
```

If the *exact* string format you described is necessary, you can change the function to:

```
for(int i=0;i<newValues.length;i++) {
 for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++) {
     newValues[i]= java.util.Arrays.toString(array[i])
               .replace(" ", "").replace("[","{").replace("]","}");
 }
}
```

Which will print out:

```
{16,11,7,6}
{10,7,6,6}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] s = new String[2];


String str = new String();
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) 
{
    str = "";
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
       array[i][j]=e.getValues (r,c);

       str += Integer.toString(array[i][j]);
       if(j != 3) str += ",";

    }

    s[i] = str;
}
```